# Delphi XE and SQL Server 2008 express connection

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server-2008, delphi-xe

How can I connect Delphi and SQL Server 2008?

I found on the internet a tutorial teaching how to use SQLConnection.

The problem is that Delphi doesn't give me an option to select MSSQL, only Interbase/Firebird and MySql.

Is there any driver missing?

I know we can use a component like Devart but I just want to use what Delphi XE offers.

Comment: What version of Delphi do you have (Pro/Enterprise?)

Answer (score 7):

If you have Delphi XE Architect or Enterprise, you should be able to connect with `TSQLConnection`. Since you don't see that, I'm guessing you have the Professional SKU.

You can use ADO via `TADOConnection`, `TADOCommand` and `TADOQuery` to work with SQL Server in XE Pro. You'll find them on the `dbGo` tab in the component palette.

Comment: @Thiago - to use ADO, you need to have SQLServer 2008 client software installed on your machine, which includes the ADO provider.

Comment: if you do use ADO, consider the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496283/why-does-ado-next-record-processing-slow-down-in-delphi